# Removing Object fails when Objects with smaller indices have been removed previously.

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to create a multi layer object representing a program, you can see what I am doing here http://codepen.io/Irish1/pen/lbjdw

say I add 3 weeks, each with 3 days each with 3 sessions. I can remove these objects as long as I dont remove say the second day before I try and remove sessions in the 3rd day

here is the code

*html*

```
<div ng-app="trainercompare">

 <div ng-controller="programsController">
    <form ng-submit="addProgram()" name='form' novalidate>

        <p>
a program
        </p>

        <button type ="button" ng-click="addWeek()"> add week</button>

        <!-- create weeks -->
        <div ng-repeat="week in program.weeks" ng-init="weekindex = $index">

            <p>
            a week
            </p>

            <!-- create days -->
            <div ng-repeat="day in week.days" ng-init="dayindex = $index">

                <p>
                a day
                </p>
                <!-- create sessions -->

                <div ng-repeat="session in day.sessions" ng-init="sessionindex = $index">
                    <h2>a Session</h2>
                    <button type ="button" ng-click="removeSession(weekindex, dayindex, sessionindex)"> Remove Session</button>
                </div>
                <button type ="button" ng-click="addSession(weekindex, dayindex)"> Add Session</button>
                <button type ="button" ng-click="removeDay(weekindex, dayindex)"> Remove day</button>
            </div>
            <button type ="button" ng-click="addDay($index)"> Add Day</button>
            <button type ="button" ng-click="remove($index)"> Remove week</button>
        </div>

        <button type="submit"> add program</button>
    </form>
 </div>

</div>
```

app.js

```
var myModule = angular.module("trainercompare", ['ui.bootstrap']);

function programsController($scope, $http) {

    var numweeks = 1;
    $scope.program = { 

    };

    $scope.addWeek = function() {

        if (isDefined($scope.program.weeks)) {
            $scope.program.weeks.push(
                {

                }
            );

        } else {
            $scope.program = { 
                weeks: [
                    {

                    }
                ]
            };
        }
    };

    $scope.addDay = function(index) {

        if (isDefined($scope.program.weeks[index].days)) {
            $scope.program.weeks[index].days.push(
                {

                }
            );

        } else {
            $scope.program.weeks[index] = { 
                days: [
                    {

                    }
                ]
            };
        }
    };

    $scope.addSession = function(weekindex, dayindex) {

        if (isDefined($scope.program.weeks[weekindex].days[dayindex].sessions)) {
            $scope.program.weeks[weekindex].days[dayindex].sessions.push(
                {

                }
            );

        } else {
            $scope.program.weeks[weekindex].days[dayindex] = { 
                sessions: [
                    {

                    }
                ]
            };
        }
    };

    $scope.remove = function(index) {
        $scope.program.weeks.splice(index, 1);

        console.log(index);

    };

    $scope.removeDay = function(weekindex, dayindex) {
        $scope.program.weeks[weekindex].days.splice(dayindex, 1);

        console.log(dayindex);

    };

    $scope.removeSession = function(weekindex, dayindex, sessionindex) {
        $scope.program.weeks[weekindex].days[dayindex].sessions.splice(dayindex, 1);

        console.log(sessionindex);

    };

    function isDefined(x) {

    return x !== undefined;
    }

    $scope.addProgram = function() {

        console.log($scope.program);

        $http.post('/programs', $scope.program).success(function(data, status) {
            if(isDefined(data.errors)) {
                console.log(data.errors);
                $scope.errors = data.errors;
                }
            if(isDefined(data.success)) {
                console.log(data.success);
                $scope.errors = [];
            }
        });

    }; 


}
```

Comment: are you saying that you are not able to remove some object as long as its previous sibling doesnt exist ?

Comment: If I delete an object I cannot delete children of subsequent siblings.  I can delete the siblings just fine I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day
Check outthis fiddle for what you wanted to implement
You removed your previous question before i had finished the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/2593/

```
var imust accompany with code
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am looking through it now and while it works for the adding and removing of weeks I am having a hard time telling if it will help the problem I am having currently as it is so different to how I was approaching it.  I will try and figure it out thank you very much

Comment: This has been a big help and wasn't as hard to figure out as I was expecting, it breaks my add methods unless I delete everything and start again. they are detailed in my question as well and if you had any advice regarding that it would be great as well.